# Most efficient way of offseting cell that contains "x"

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using `Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Columns(1)` provisionally to offset all cells that contain "x" one column to the left, however it seems to be very memory consuming and not very reliable as I can't choose to offset only "x" values.

Is there any way I can make only the cells on which this contition was met to be offset, and on a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would probably want to try something like this

```
For i = 1 To 100
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "x" Then
       ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next
```

just set the 100 for however many rows you have. I'm not even sure this would run any faster than what you have. Unless I am missing your goal here.

and if you want to go through all cells in the sheet

```
For Each rcell In ActiveSheet.Cells
    If recll.Column >= 1 And rcell.Value = "x" Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rcell.Row, rcell.Column - 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(rcell.Row, rcell.Column).Value
    End If
Next
```

but this one would presumably take a really long time. Ideally you should use nested loops if you know the last row and column you are using. This way you only iterate of cells that you believe contain data.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the below answer, but with a For-Each loop and for the whole range:

```
Sub MoveOver()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")

    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value = "x" Then c.Offset(0, -1) = c.Value
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: you have to be careful with this though, If you set your range to (A:C) for example, you will get errors using offset like that. So you have to be careful to start at column 2 or beyond, and do a check for column #